# Generate sequence numbers for a range and decrementer

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table like below and It has start range and end range columns.

```
+------+----------+--------+--+
|  f1  | start_r  | end_r  |
+------+----------+--------+--+
| ABC  | 31       | 29     |
+------+----------+--------+--+
```

I need to use the values in start_r and end_r and produce the output like below (generate the sequence number between the start and end range decremented by 1)

```
 f1   seq_no

 ABC   31
 ABC   30
 ABC   29
```

I just need an approach to to generate the values .. is there any buitin function in hive for this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit:
Replaced `split(space(start_r - end_r - 1),'')`
with `split(space(start_r - end_r),' ')`

```
select  t.f1
       ,t.start_r - pe.i as seq_no 

from   (select 'ABC' as f1,31 as start_r,29 as end_r)                t 
       lateral view posexplode(split(space(start_r - end_r),' ')) pe as i,s
;
```

---

```
hive> select t.f1,t.start_r - pe.i as seq_no from (select 'ABC' as f1,31 as start_r,29 as end_r) t lateral view posexplode(split(space(start_r - end_r - 1),'')) pe as i,s;
OK
ABC 31
ABC 30
ABC 29
```

Replace `(select 'ABC' as f1,31 as start_r,29 as end_r)` with your table

Comment: Dudu Markovitz,
I am getting only 2 rows... 29 is missing..!

`ABC     31
ABC     30`

Comment: Interesting. As you can see I have tested the code. Please show me what are the results of `select split(space(31 - 29- 1),'');`

Comment: + `hive --version`

Comment: I am using Hortonworks Distribution 2.4.2 version. I think the hive versionis 1.2.1..  The query which you gave in comment produces the output like below..
`[" ",""]`

Comment: I'm working on Hortonworks Hive 0.14.0.2.2.9.0-3393 and the query returns `[""," ",""]`. You can change `space(start_r - end_r - 1)` to `space(start_r - end_r)` but I wonder if the difference is due to the different versions or caused by something else.

Comment: changed to `space(start_r - end_r)` and it worked.. Thanks..!!  I think its because of different version..

Comment: Hi, can you please check if you used `split(...,' ')` (with space) instead of `split(...,'')` (empty string)? This results in a one less element

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query
;WITH n(n) AS
(
    SELECT 31
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n-1 FROM n WHERE n > 29 
)
SELECT n FROM n ORDER BY n Desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);

Comment: Hive, not SQL Server